# JDBC executeBatch() hangs without error in PostgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.2

I try load 50000 rows in table with 200 columns. I do `executeBatch()` every 1000 rows. And I get lock for this table. The same code works for MS SQL and Oracle but with `postgresql` I get this issue. When I decrease `executeBatch` number from 1000 to 75 all works correctly.

Is there any param in config file witch responding for batch buffer size?

Same issue http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c44a1bc0-dcb1-4b57-8106-e50f9303b7d1@79g2000hsk.googlegroups.com

Comment: have you check the memory usage of your application maybe the driver consumes more memory such that the GC is frequently sought. Maybe simply increasing the heap size could be enough

Comment: I run this separately from app. Just load data from file in database.

Comment: if so remove the tag java then

Comment: jdbc implemented with java...

Comment: if you know that it is not java related don't pollute the tag, just remove it. Otherwise it is an open door to anything you could also add for example NetBeans, Windows, Intel, ... it is endless. I hope you better understand my point now

Comment: Did you check that your Java process isn't blocked by some other transaction? (through `pg_stat_activity`). See https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name, Yes I check. It's only one transaction in database.From java handing looks like long writing in socket (see scrennshot) https://www.dropbox.com/s/nin878syvkluiza/thread.png?dl=0

Comment: Please include information like that in the question, not as an external link. But that sounds like a network problem, not a Postgres problem.

Comment: a_horse_with_no_name,Yes I guess that problem related to socket buffer size and hanging only in postgre jdbc implementation.Same problem, please look http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c44a1bc0-dcb1-4b57-8106-e50f9303b7d1@79g2000hsk.googlegroups.com

Comment: There are timeouts too (statement_timeout and lock_timeout).

Comment: Joop Eggen, I try use timeout but without success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I execute insert statements in batch for tables with a large number of columns occurs hanging, when call statement.executeBatch().
It is specific for postgresql jdbc driver.
To avoid this issue we should increase buffer size params(SO_SNDBUF, SO_RCVBUF) for socket.

For Windows we have to create such params in register:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \SYSTEM \CurrentControlSet \Services \Afd \Parameters]
```

DefaultReceiveWindow(type=DWORD) = 1640960(Decimal)
DefaultSendWindow(type=DWORD) = 1640960(Decimal)

This number(1640960) I get from internet as general recommendation!
And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you need to look for the following things.

1. Are you able to actually get a lock for the table?
2. Do you have other java code locks that you are waiting for?

In general the first place to check is the `pg_stat_activity system` view which will show you the query being executed and whether it is active, idle, waiting, etc.  Then if it is waiting (i.e. `waiting` is `t`), then you will want to check the `pg_locks` view and see what else may have a lock on anything in the relation.

If waiting is not true, then you are better off checking your java code for client-side locks but since this works for MySQL and Oracle, I assume this is less of an issue.

There is one other thing to be aware of.  I am not sure about MySQL and Oracle here but PostgreSQL limits you to one query at a time per connection.  You might have some locking there?

Comment: I have same issue like in this case http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/c44a1bc0-dcb1-4b57-8106-e50f9303b7d1@79g2000hsk.googlegroups.com

Comment: in pg_stat_activity for my insert query state=active waiting=f. No locks

Comment: For connection pools I would definitely suspect Java object locks in the pooling logic.

Comment: However, if insert query state is active, then PostgreSQL is running the query.  This doesnt suggest at that point a client-side problem.  Rather one would probably look at performance of your insert itself.